# Fragment keeps on crashing. How to reload a fragment using fragment transaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-volley, fragmenttransaction

I am trying to reload my fragment using this code:

```
private void reloadFragment() {

    Fragment newFragment = new FragmentList();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

but my app keeps crashing when i call the method.. i dont know what is wrong i get this error in my console:

```
  05-12 17:30:53.354 10168-10168/comb.example.shahid.carrottechapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: comb.example.shahid.carrottechapp, PID: 10168
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
         at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:137)
         at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.<init>(ImageRequest.java:71)
         at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:219)
         at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:149)
         at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:198)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1190)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.layoutDecorated(RecyclerView.java:6976)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1428)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1190)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1190)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1190)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1954)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1808)
         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1717)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:628)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:563)
         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15901)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5103)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2420)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6438)
         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:795)
         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:598)
         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:567)
         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:781)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

I have been trying to resolve this since morning don't know what is wrong with this please help me

Comment: share code of FragmentList class

Comment: The error is occuring when you are executing ".hashCode()" function on a null String Object. Since you are saying app crashes when you load your Fragment, then the error is inside your fragments onCreateView() method. Please Check. The hashCode() method must be getting executed inside the onCreateView().

Comment: @AkhilSoman hasCode() is mostly called by java for equality checks, and the string is null, hence an equality check resolves to that error. i doubt he called it explicitly

Comment: @Shahid Sarwar : Post our full code to look into